# Addresses found in wallet.dat that start 00 14

Tags: bitcoin-core, address, encryption

I found a list of addresses in my dumped wallet.dat file that all start 00 14...    They are script=1.

What are these encoded with and how to decode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than likely these are native segwit address scripts. Native segwit `scriptPubKey` start with `0014` followed by a 20-byte public key hash. There is an [online tool](https://slowli.github.io/bech32-buffer/) available for encoding the public key hash into its native segwit address representation. Note that although the risk of using such tools is minimal in terms of security, there is a possible risk toward privacy. I have not personally verified/reviewed the code for this online tool and you should proceed with caution.

Remove the `00 14` section and paste the remaining 40-character string (20 bytes) into the "Data" field. The associated bitcoin address will be displayed on the right-hand side under "Encoded data".